# node: managing SQL files with variable replacement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have large SQL statements that I would like to store as separate files (with syntax highlighting etc). I like the accepted solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343095/where-to-store-sql-commands-for-execution).

In my use case, I write SQL in Javascript Template Literal syntax for variable replacement. So my file looks like

```sql
-- some_file.sql
select col1, col2, col3
from   my_table
where  col1 = '${val1}'
and    col2 between ${val2} and ${val3}
```

In fact this way of writing queries started from using template literals initially before the queries grew and demanded their own file.

The question is how to achieve template literals like evaluation for a query string read using `fs.readFileSync` without having to do the dreaded `eval`? I looked into [es6-template-render](http://andreafalzetti.github.io/blog/2016/10/22/render-es6-javascript-template-literals-contained-variable.html), however that implementation is not suited for variables in the execution context; i.e. not specifying a separate `context` parameter, but implicitly using the variables (global/local) available in the environment during runtime.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies if my assumption is incorrect, but the quotes around `'${val1}'` suggest you're planning to use string substitution rather than parameterized queries. **Don't do that.** :-) Never use string substitution to put values into SQL queries. Let me introduce you to [my friend Bobby](https://bobby-tables.com/):

[image]

Use parameterized queries instead.

For instance, you might use a format very much like you have, just without any quotes around `${val1}`:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from   my_table
where  col1 = ${val1}
and    col2 between ${val2} and ${val3}
```

Then your code could convert that into a query appropriate to your DB API. Many of them use `?` placeholders, so for instance (here I'm using `node-mysql2` as the DB API, but the specific API isn't the point):

```
const rexParam = /(?<!\$)\$\{([^}]+)\}/g;
function doQuery(sql, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const values = [];
        const preppedSql = sql.replace(rexParam, (_, paramName) => {
            const value = params[paramName];
            if (value === undefined) { // Or do an `in` check if you want to allow `undefined`
                throw new Error(`Missing parameter ${paramName}`);
            }
            values.push(value);
            return "?";
        });
        return connection.execute(
            preppedSql,
            values,
            function(err, results, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve({results, fields});
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

That spins through the string, replacing the `${val1}` and such tokens with `?` and at the same time filling in an array of values to pass to the parameterized query function.

(Note the negative lookbehind so that `$${...}` isn't expanded, just like in template literals. The regex is a bit primitive, but should suffice for SQL I'd think...)

Live example just dumping out the string and values:

```js
const sql =
    "select col1, col2, col3\n" +
    "from   my_table\n" +
    "where  col1 = ${val1}\n" +
    "and    col2 between ${val2} and ${val3}";

const rexParam = /(?<!\$)\$\{([^}]+)\}/g;
function doQuery(sql, params) {
    const values = [];
    const preppedSql = sql.replace(rexParam, (_, paramName) => {
        const value = params[paramName];
        if (value === undefined) { // Or do an `in` check if you want to allow `undefined`
            throw new Error(`Missing parameter '${paramName}'`);
        }
        values.push(value);
        return "?";
    });
    console.log(preppedSql);
    console.log(values);
}

doQuery(sql, {val1: "one", val2: 2, val3: 20});
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! Yes, it is indeed string substitution. However, the value of the string to be substituted comes from a previously defined variable of the same name.

I'm trying to find out why prepared statements weren't used in the first place, will need some time to dig out the details. From the looks of it though, the publicly available db-apis for Presto ([presto-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/presto-client) and [prestodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prestodb)), nor the one built in-house seem to support binding of params.

Comment: *"However, the value of the string to be substituted comes from a previously defined variable of the same name."* The key question is: Where do the values in those variables come from? Because if they're user-sourced at **any** stage, you cannot trust them. *"From the looks of it though, the publicly available db-apis for Presto (presto-client and prestodb), nor the one built in-house seem to support binding of params."* I don't know Presto, but a search for "presto parameterized query turns up [this](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/prepare.html), which suggest it exists. Happy coding!

Comment: Very useful when you want to store parameterized queries in a separate file without requiring sql package.